# Logic Gate Power in Proteus

Tags: power, digital-logic, logic-gates, proteus, vcc

[image]

Can someone explain to me how you can power (vcc, vdd whatever) a logic gate in Proteus, with only the input and output pins being shown? Thanks in advance.

The above is the circuit I want to implement. I read that this is the circuit of a basic oscillator.I want to connect the power lines with the power source. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can find it in terminal mode on left

Answer (score 0):

**For simulation, there's no need to power that kind of ICs, because ISIS can simulate them with or without a power.**

If you need the power connection for PCB design purposes then POWER terminal is what you are looking for. You can find it under TERMINAL MODE to the left:

[image]

Once you place a POWER terminal, the invisible VCC/VDD pins of the chips will connect to this terminal automatically.

Comment: What if I want to connect them to another circuit, not directly to the power supply?

Comment: When I try this circuit I get the error 'No power supply specified for net VDD and/or VSS in Power Rail Configuration'.

Comment: @Mats POWER terminal provides 5V by default but you can connect that POWER terminal to the output of another circuit so that the invisible VCC/VDD pins can connect another circuit block.

Comment: @Mats Put the schematic into your original question so we can suggest something.

Comment: I've added a circuit diagram to the original question.Can you help me?

Comment: @Mats What's the purpose? Simulation or PCB design?

Comment: At the moment, just simulation.

Comment: @Mats Alright, open ISIS, go to 'Pick Devices' by clicking 'P' button to the left. Type "NAND gate" into the 'Keywords' textbox. Double click on '4011' to put it to the Devices bin. Then type "minres1k" into the Keywords textbox, this will bring you a 1k resistor. Double click on it to put it into the Devices bin. Then type "ceramic capacitor 100n". This will bring you a lot of non-polarized capacitors. Pick one and put it into Devices bin. Then setup the circuit. Note that **there's no need to power the circuit**. The IC is self-powered with 5VDC.